# Block access to specific path with minifilters

Tags: driver, minifilter

I am trying to write a minifilter that block access to any file within a specific path. I have been able to do it for any path in C:. This is what I´ve done. First, I declare:

`const WCHAR* internal_drives[] = { L"C:" };`

Then, in `instant_setup` I start the minifilter for C: by doing:

```
        int internal_drives_length = sizeof internal_drives / sizeof * internal_drives;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < internal_drives_length; i++)
        {
            if (wcscmp(ctx->Name.Buffer, internal_drives[i]) == 0)
            {
                status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
            }
        }
```

I can block access to C: then by adding in functions: `mini_pre_create`, `mini_post_create`:

```
    status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
    data->IoStatus.Status = status;
    data->IoStatus.Information = 0;
```

That works, I am able to block the access to any file in C:

But I´d like to be able to specify to which folder I want to block the access. I´ve trying specifying the path in the variable `internal_drives` but It does not work, I am blocking nothing :

`const WCHAR* internal_drives[] = { L"D:\\path" };`

Am I missing something? is there a more correct way to do this with minifilters? I am a complete beginner with minifilters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You setup to the drivers, then you filter in the specific IRP_MJ_CREATE. To do that, you have to use FltGetFileNameInformation plus FltParseFileNameInformation.

Do note that the filesystem does not work with DOS name drive letters, so you will have to transform \Device\Harddiskvolumex\folder\file.txt to c:\folder\file.txt. You can do that mapping on setup.

Comment: Many thanks. It seems I was filtering well, just changing the path to  \Device\Harddiskvolumex instead of C:\path and it works.

Comment: Such mapping may change between harddisk changes, which is common if its removable devices). Therefore you can either mantain an active list of which is which during the setup of the disk (or during the operation itself but that's inefficient) using IoVolumeDeviceToDosName

Comment: Another question related to this one. Is there any function to convert a DOS path to this format: \Device\Harddiskvolumex\... ? For the moment I am just manually inserting the path, but I´d like to convert it from a C:\... path

Comment: ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject then ZwQuerySymbolicLinkObject. Depending situation, open the file then ObReferenceObjectByHandle and finally IoQueryFileDosDeviceName

Comment: I am getting a blue screen after doing these steps, so I guess something is not going well but I cannot figure out myself what, probably due to my lack of knowledge. I´ll prepare a minimal example and post it in another minifilter thread. Thanks.